# Copy unix mail (received by sendmail) to a linux directory (individually)

Tags: java, email, archiving, procmail

Does anyone know a way to copy all new arrived emails (on Fedora Linux), to store in a Linux directory (not in some other mail folder, but on the Linux file system directory)?

We use Procmail as a delivery system. I looked at may docs, but they all show only two patterns regarding copying:

1. Append to mail.bkp -- not sure why append all mails on one file?
2. Put everything in /dev/null -- to handle spam

I need to have 'light weight' mechanism to copy/archive all new mails to a Linux file system like

- /home/username/data/archive/mail1.x
- /home/username/data/archive/mail2.x
- /home/username/data/archive/mail3.x

and than I am planning to use Java directory listener to read those emails in parallel.

Please give me your valuable advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your issue would be to use your procmailrc file to save a copy of the mail to a Maildir format.

Maildir keeps each mail as a separate file, which solves your one problem. Additionally, if you copy the mail it will still go the the other existing locations:

your procmailrc would have the following (or similar lines) near the top:

```
:0c:
$HOME/Maildir/
```

You would need to create the folder `Maildir` in your home directory still.

Comment: I tried this in .procmailrc file. but I see new emails and does not get copied into /home/username/data/archive ..

Comment: But it is getting copied to `/home/username/Maildir/new/`, right?

Comment: my entry in .procmailrc looks like this
`:0c:
$/home/username/data/archive`      -- and I dont see new mails copied there

Comment: The dollar sign there is wrong, and the lock file (second colon after `:0c`) is superfluous.  Notice the difference between the variable `$HOME` and the literal, absolute path `/home/username (which the value of `$HOME` could typically be).

Comment: you are correct it is a typo. I have an absolute dir path

Comment: @Sendi_t - note that you need to have a trailing `/` after the location to indicate it is a directory, which procmailrc will interpret as being a "maildir format" folder, as in: `/home/username/data/archive/` - that last `/` is significant.

Comment: @StackMonkey -- you were correct.. the / at the end was missing from my entry, I tested it and it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Delivering to a directory only to have an elaborate system to monitor that directory is rather awkward.  If your Java program can read standard input, just pipe directly to that.

```
:0
| /path/to/java -crash -boom -bang -coredump=always
```

Comment: the reason I don't want to call java from procmailrc is -- apparently it is invoking java for each email..creating so many VMs each processing just 1 email..:(.. so I just want to copy all emails in one dir and then process many mails..